# Automatic invocation a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Right so I have been investigating the Terminal-Icons git repo because I have been wanting to make my own shell formatter [using powershell and csharp]. While most of it is completed,I noticed an interesting phrase in one of the files [https://github.com/devblackops/Terminal-Icons/blob/main/Terminal-Icons/Public/Format-TerminalIcons.ps1] :

*List a directory. Terminal-Icons will be invoked automatically for display*

Now, I do not quite understand **how** or **what** they are doing here[I am new to writing powershell code]. The main thing that I want to understand is how they are formatting the output of the *Get-ChildItem* cmdlet and how I could implement something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you link to, [`Format-TerminalIcons`](https://github.com/devblackops/Terminal-Icons/blob/main/Terminal-Icons/Public/Format-TerminalIcons.ps1), is being called from custom *for-display formatting data* that the [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) project at hand associates with the .NET types that cmdlets such a [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) output, namely [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo).

In other words: the project makes use of a standard PowerShell feature that allows associating .NET types with custom for-display formatting instructions that are automatically applied when instances of such types render to the display.

As the `Terminal-Icon` [read-me](https://github.com/devblackops/Terminal-Icons) states:

> It [the module] uses a custom [format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6) file that inspects the items being displayed and looks up their appropriate icon based on name or extension.

Specifically, that `*.format.ps1xml` file is [`Terminal-Icons.format.ps1xml`](https://github.com/devblackops/Terminal-Icons/blob/main/Terminal-Icons/Terminal-Icons.format.ps1xml), and in it you'll find multiple calls to `Format-TerminalIcons`; e.g.:

```xml
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>
                                    Terminal-Icons\Format-TerminalIcons $_
                                </ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
```

See also:

- [Format Schema XML Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/format-schema-xml-reference)
- [Writing a PowerShell Formatting File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/writing-a-powershell-formatting-file)